# How do I make a query listing certain elements of a column that are in a subquery table, SQL. EXISTS, IN?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'll just show you guys an example: I got these tables:

Table: Car Mark

```
Name | Manufacturer
------------------- 
POLO   VOLKSWAGEN  
A6     AUDI
911    PORSCHE
```

Then I get this sub table, from about three tables, from a subquery:

```
Manufacturer |  Num of rented cars, by clients age > 50
-------------------------------------------------------
VOLKSWAGEN                      2 
AUDI                            3
```

My question is: how do I select the manufacturer from `Car Mark` that exist in this subquery?

I just want an output:

```
Manufacturer
---------------
VOLKSWAGEN
AUDI
```

Comment: `SELECT Manufacturer FROM ... WHERE Manufacturer IN (SELECT t1.Manufacturer FROM ... t1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it different way, I rather the first one because the explain plain looks simpler and code is easy to read.

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a20be/1)**

Check the explain plan of each query with or without index.

Last two have the exact same plan. My guess optimizer translate those to the same query.

```
SELECT C.[Manufacturer]
FROM  cars C
LEFT JOIN rented R
       ON C.[Manufacturer] = R.[Manufacturer]
WHERE R.[Manufacturer] IS NOT NULL;

SELECT C.[Manufacturer]
FROM  cars C
WHERE C.[Manufacturer] IN ( SELECT [Manufacturer]
                            FROM rented R );

SELECT C.[Manufacturer]
FROM  cars C
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT [Manufacturer]
               FROM rented R 
               WHERE R.[Manufacturer] = C.[Manufacturer]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select Manufacturer
from Car_Mark
where Manufacturer in (
    select Manufacturer 
    from (
        --your subquery...
    ) x
)
```